# Encouraging users to flag off-topic posts before making a comment that it is off-topic to avoid cross-posting

Tags: discussion, migration

I have seen many examples on SO and other websites where users tell the OP that it is off-topic and it belongs to X website. It leads to cross-posting by the OP because they don't know about migration.

Specifically many people tell that this belongs to codereview for reviews. But due to people not flagging the question is cross-posted. A simple comment explaining that it has been flagged for migration would be very helpful.

How to make people on SO and other sites aware that they should flag for moderator attention before making such comments so such cross-posting is avoided? Is there a way? Like a community news page or something?

Comment: Not disagreeing as I've thought the same in the past (despite me doing exactly what you are saying we shouldn't do at times), but part of the problem is a new user won't know necessarily how the migration process works and how to tell the question wasn't migrated.  I think we need a [meta-tag:faq] post about the migration process that can be linked too when commenting

Comment: Making a comment that it has been flagged for migration and it will be migrated soon should be helpful. But yes, new users not familiar with SE would be simply confused. A beginner guide about migration would be useful.

Comment: Not all questions are *suited* for migration, nor is Codereview a listed in the OT target sites. That requires a manual migration by a moderator, and *that* usually only happens if the post is of sufficient quality. If a post ends up cross-posted, then closed on SO as OT, that's sorta alright. The target site will of course still have to deal with a potentially low-quality post, but they have their own closing mechanisms.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not saying that all questions should be migrated. I am saying that the questions which need to be migrated should be flagged before telling the user that this needs to be migrated. A little comment saying that with a mention that it has flagged for migration can avoid unnecessary cross-posting. It can be handled on the target site but it can also be easily avoided. Same goes for posts migrated to SO. It will reduce cross-posting. It also puts off new users sometimes when they are told that it is migrated and then told that it shouldn't have been cross-posted.

Comment: I know what you were saying; I am adding a little more context, and expressing the opinion that mostly, cross-posting is not *that* big a problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It isn't a huge problem that cannot be handled by the community but it puts off new-users sometimes that they are told to migrate and after they post again they are told it was good where it was. For a small website like codereview that is kinda important IMHO.